twailwindcss media query works differently on aws ec2 and vercel for same app
class="p-2 flex justify-center flex-col lg:flex-row gap-2"

output for vercel

output for aws ec2

working perfect wiht vercel deployment

Their priority depends on which appeared later in the stylesheet. One quick fix is to replace flex-col to max-lg:flex-col, but you might want to figure out what is done differently in the deployment in ec2 that causes Tailwind to generate a stylesheet that the break-points are not ordered correctly.
